# siunitx: SI number running into margin

Tags: margins, siunitx

I have a few instances where `siunitx` numbers are running into the margin. They aren't particularary long, eg. `\SI{500}{kV}`. I can't seem to find an applicable setting in the documentation. Is there a nice way to fix this globally?

Comment: You are probably better of rewriting your text slightly. Unit and quantum should not be broken from each other.

Comment: You should post  a short, yet complete code,  reproducing the problem.

Comment: You can try to increase `\tolerance` parameter, or put `\sloppy` option at the worst.

Comment: @daleif, I'm not suggesting breaking the Unit and quantum; rather inserting a \newline before the number.

Comment: No! Never! Rewrite/rephrase is your best option. When you resort to using newlines in the text then you're really doing it wrong. Forced newlines has no place in the text.

Comment: @daleif, sorry, haha, that's not what I meant. I response to your first comment, I want the result of that, ie keep the number and unit together, but on a new line. I'd rather not have to rewrite it.